# Do I need a database for ELK data log analytics?

Tags: mongodb, logging, kibana, elasticsearch-5, filebeat

I'm new to ELK stack. I want to design a log analytic dashboard. So Do I need a database like mongodb or cassandra to store the log files.

1. If so which database to choose.?
2. Does it affect the performance of querying ..? will it be fast ?
3. Also to query back past month/year logs does the elasticsearch saves the logs.?

I will be feeding huge log files from different servers. so what is the best way. Any suggestions or references.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use any database, although the best practice is to use elasticsearch above any database.
Elasticsearch save the logs until you delete them.